# проверка соответствия текста в файле определенному шаблону

Tags: java

Нужно создать подключение к клиенту на сервере и высылать ему команды которые записаны в файле (пусть его имя test.txt).
Команда имеет вид:

<уникальный идентификатор устройства>;<действие>;<относительная координата по оси X>;<относительная координата по оси Y>;<цвет>\n

В случае если команда не соответствует формату мы её игнорируем. Вот у меня вопрос, как сделать вот эту проверку на соответствен.

Comment: зависит от типов данных, которые передаете. может вам распарсить ее и проверять ?

Comment: регулярными выражениями.